# adjusting height of StackLayout element

Tags: android, xamarin, cross-platform

I'm really new to Xamarin Forms and I was just given the task to adjust the UI for the Android version of this application. On Android phones, the UI looks fine, however on tablets it's a little small. So I've developed a new page to go to when the device is a tablet, however I can't seem to adjust the height of the StackLayout elements. Here's the code:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>
      <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Fill" Spacing="0" Padding="0" Margin="0">
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Fill" HeightRequest="60" Padding="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
          <Label VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="19" Margin="14,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="White" ></Label>
          <Image VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="30" Source="imgArrow.png"></Image>
        </StackLayout>
        <BoxView Margin="0,2,0,0" HeightRequest="0.5" BackgroundColor="White" />
      </StackLayout>
    </ViewCell>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Know matter what values I put in the HeightRequest fields, it always looks the same. I'm sure I'm missing something completely fundamental here. Here's what it looks like on screen https://imgur.com/MAHgOgr. I'm just wanting it to take up more space which will involve increasing the font size, but when I do that it just looks awful. [pic with font size 40](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsBt5.jpg). Any help I can get is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to set the "HasUnevenRows" property of the listview to true?

I think it will fix your problem with the font size

Answer (score 0):

1. detect if it's tablet/phone, set correct heights to variables you would use
2. since you are in a DataTemplate bind HeightRequest to the variables you have set.

for a simple case outside of datatemplates you can give x:name to elements, then in the constructor set widthrequests with those names.